# Finiteness of the normalization of an algebra over a DVR

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a DVR, $A$ a finitely generated integral $R$-algebra, and $A'$ the normalization of $A$ in the fraction field of $A$.
Then is $A'$ finite as an $A$-module?

I know that if $R$ is a field, then it's true.
And I know this is true, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602626.pdf), section 2 in page 8.
But I don't know its proof.
So please show it or suggest some references.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property you state is related to the property of $R$ being *excellent,* and more specifically to weaker condition of whether $R$ has the *N-2* property or the stronger *Nagata* property; see [[Matsumura](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=575344), §31] and [[Illusie–Laszlo–Orgogozo](http://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/orgogozo/travaux_de_Gabber/GTG/GTG.pdf), Exp. I].

Not all DVR's satisfy your property. We give an example below, due to Nagata. On the other hand, both Dedekind domains of characteristic zero and complete local rings are excellent [[Illusie–Laszlo–Orgogozo](http://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/orgogozo/travaux_de_Gabber/GTG/GTG.pdf), Exp. I, Prop. 3.1 and §4], hence satisfy your property.

**Example** [[Nagata](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=460307), App. A1, Ex. 3]**.** We give an example of a DVR $R$ and an algebra of finite type $A$ over $R$ such that the normalization $A'$ of $A$ in $\operatorname{Frac}(A)$ is not finite over $A$. Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p > 0$ such that $[k : k^p] = \infty$, and consider the ring
$$R = \biggl\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i \in k[[x]] \biggm\vert [k^p(a_0,a_1,\ldots):k^p] < \infty \biggr\}.$$
This is a DVR by [[Nagata](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=460307), App. A1, (E3.1)]. Let $\{b_1,b_2,\ldots\} \subseteq k$ be a sequence of elements in $k$ that are $p$-independent over $k^p$. Set
$$c = \sum_{i=0}^\infty b_ix^i,$$
and consider the ring $A = R[c]$. Then, the normalization $A'$ of $A$ in $\operatorname{Frac}(A)$ is not finite over $A$ by [[Nagata](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=460307), App. A1, (E3.2)].